# SSRS 2012 without SSL

Tags: ssl, ssrs-2012

We are writing a deployment package to install SSRS 2012 on client servers.  Some of them may have a certificate installed, but in all cases we do **not** want the installation to force the SSL (https) connection; we always want the non-SSL address to be accessible.  I know the rsconfig file can be edited after deployment, but we would like the deployment and configuration to be 100% automated.

Is there a command-line switch or install-time configuration setting to tell the SSRS installation to not require the SSL connection, even if a certificate has been installed?

EDIT: After searching there doesn't seem to be a way to set this at install-time.  Anyone have a way of changing the setting via code after installation?

Answer (score 1):

> ### [delete sslcert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/desktop/cc307229(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> Deletes SSL server certificate bindings and the corresponding client
>   certificate policies for an IP address and port.
>
> ```
> delete sslcert [ipport=]IP Address:port
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> [**ipport=**]IP Address:port
>
> - Specifies the IPv4 or IPv6 address and port for which the SSL    certificate bindings will be deleted.
>
> **Examples**
>
> `delete sslcert ipport=1.1.1.1:443`
>
> `delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443`
>
> `delete sslcert ipport=[::]:443`
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/windows/desktop/cc307229(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>

Comment: This may work, but in our situation deleting the SSL certificate isn't really a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

> ### [SSRS SSL Certificate Nightmare](http://thinknook.com/ssrs-ssl-certificate-nightmare-2011-06-28/)
>
> Issue a command to delete the binding for this specific IP:Port combination:
>
> `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=[::]:443`
>
> <sub>[source](http://thinknook.com/ssrs-ssl-certificate-nightmare-2011-06-28/)</sub>

### Further Resources

- [**NETSH**](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html)